# Datetime parse and format in C++

Tags: c++, datetime, c++17, c++20

I'm using time_point the first time.
I want to parse datetime from string and found a difference when returning back to string from 1 hour.

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point timePoint;
std::stringstream ss("2021-01-01 00:00:09+01");
std::chrono::from_stream(ss, "%F %T%z", timePoint);  
  // timePoint == {_MyDur={_MyRep=16094556090000000 } }
std::string timePointStr = std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %T}", floor<std::chrono::seconds>(timePoint));
  // timePointStr = "2020/12/31 23:00:09"
```

I don't know what is wrong: the timepoint and the parsing or the formatting to string?
How can I get the same format as the parsed one?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? [Edit] your question to elaborate please!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: The post *does* eplain what went wrong. He converted the string `"2021-01-01 00:00:09+01"` to a time-point and then back to a string. But the result wasn't the same.

Comment: Isn't `"+01"` is for "GMT" so you just got value for `+00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

Explanation:

`system_clock::time_point`, and more generally, all `time_point`s based on `system_clock`, have the semantics of [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  This is a count of time since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, excluding leap seconds.

So when "2021-01-01 00:00:09+01" is parsed into a `system_clock::time_point`, the "2021-01-01 00:00:09" is interpreted as *local time*, and the "+01" is used to transform that local time into UTC.  When formatting back out, there is no corresponding transformation back to local time (though that is possible with additional syntax<sup>1</sup>).  The format statement simply prints out the UTC time (an hour earlier).

If you would prefer to parse "2021-01-01 00:00:09+01" without the transformation to UTC, that can be done by parsing into a `std::chrono::local_time` of whatever precision you desire.  For example:

```
std::chrono::local_seconds timePoint;
std::stringstream ss("2021-01-01 00:00:09+01");
from_stream(ss, "%F %T%z", timePoint);
...
```

Now when you print it back out, you will get "2021/01/01 00:00:09".  However the value in the `rep` is now 1609459209 (3600 seconds later).

---

<sup>1</sup> To format out at `sys_time` as a `local_time` with a UTC offset of 1h it is necessary to choose a `time_zone` with a UTC offset of 1h *at least* at the UTC time you are formatting.  For example the IANA time zone of "Etc/GMT-1" *always* has an offset of 1h ... yes, the signs of the offset are reversed.  Using this to transform 2020-12-31 23:00:09 UTC back to 2021-01-01 00:00:09 would look like:

```
std::chrono::sys_seconds timePoint;
std::stringstream ss("2021-01-01 00:00:09+01");
std::chrono::from_stream(ss, "%F %T%z", timePoint);
// timePoint == 2020-12-31 23:00:09 UTC
std::string timePointStr = std::format("{:%Y/%m/%d %T}",
                               std::chrono::zoned_time{"Etc/GMT-1", timePoint});
cout << timePointStr << '\n';  // 2021/01/01 00:00:09
```

*Disclaimer:*  I do not currently have a way to verify that MSVC supports the "Etc/GMT-1" `std::chrono::time_zone`.

Fwiw, using "Africa/Algiers" or "Europe/Amsterdam" in place of "Etc/GMT-1" *should* give the same result for this specific time stamp.  And if your computer has its local time zone set to something that has a 1h UTC offset for this timestamp, then `std::chrono::current_zone()` in place of of "Etc/GMT-1" will also give the same result.